# Why do I get the error "Missing } in template expression"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I try to evaluate this expression in **Node.js v8.9.4**:

```
`${ xxx 123 }`
```

It throws the error

> Missing } in template expression

I understand that the expression above should cause
an error because the contents inside `${}` are not
valid JavaScript. But why does the error-message
claim a `}` is missing? I can clearly see an opening
`{` and a closing `}`. Why is it saying a `}`
is missing?

Comment: `xxx 123` is not a valid expression

Comment: `Why is it saying a '}' is missing?` because, when trying to figure out what you're trying to do, I guess that's the parser error that comes up

Comment: I think because it expects `${ xxx }`?

Comment: Because it is expecting the the interpolation to be closed between expressions; xxx and 123

Comment: Yeah, Jorg is correct, I think the problem is that `xxx 123` is not a valid expression, so however it is trying to parse it this is the best error it can come up with for whatever it things you are trying to do.  Are you perhaps intending it to be `\`${xxx} 123\`` where `xxx` is some variable you have saved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say there is a closing brace, but the js execution doesn't get that far because it breaks between xxx and 123.

The syntax expects opening brace, statement, then closing brace. It gets opening brace, statement then another statement. So at that point the error is precisely what is says. And in fact, if you add the brace as it suggests, it will work `${ xxx } 123 }` :D
It's not what you intended, but you can't say it is wrong

Comment: Makes sense of course. I just think the error message could be clearer.  Something like "Invalid expression within template expression". Is the error "missing }" or is it "Invalid expression between `${` and `}`" ?

Comment: @PanuLogic Compilers are like toddlers.  They take everything you say literally and throw an imcomprehensible tantrum the second something unexpected happens.  Don't try to make sense of their gibberish, just curse them and move on.